# Mix-blend-mode: weird (temp) black background during SVG animation on android

Tags: android, animation, blend, gsap, mix-blend-mode

I'm spinning a few rectangles atop each other, and their colors interact with using the css's mix-blend-mode.

In all browsers it's fine, but on chrome on Android there is a black background that is generated around the svg's rectangle shape while it's rotating. Once it settles into position, the black background disappears.

Pen: https://codepen.io/sashakevich/pen/YVMmZV

html:

```
<svg id="sl_logo" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 379.94 62.8"><g id="mark"><rect id="bar-1" class="cls-1" x="20.04" width="12.1" height="56" rx="3.24" ry="3.24"/><rect id="bar-2" class="cls-2" x="20.9" y="0.5" width="12.1" height="56" rx="3.24" ry="3.24" transform="matrix(0.5, 0.87, -0.87, 0.5, 37.29, -9.59)"/><rect id="bar-3" class="cls-3" x="20.9" y="0.5" width="12.1" height="56" rx="3.24" ry="3.24" transform="matrix(-0.5, 0.87, 0.87, 0.5, 15.5, -9.59)"/></g></svg>
```

css:

```
#bar-1, #bar-2, #bar-3 {
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
}
#bar-1 {
  fill:#ed4237;
}
#bar-2 {
  fill:#29aae2;
}
#bar-3 {
  fill:#7ab642;
}
```

js

```
TweenMax.from("#bar-2", .35, {rotation:0, transformOrigin:"center center", delay:.4});
TweenMax.from("#bar-3", .7, {rotation:0, transformOrigin:"center center", delay:.4});
TweenMax.from("#letters", .7, {x:-40, opacity:0, transformOrigin:"left", delay:.4});
```

Any ideas how to get it to behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 2 hours later I have a solution....

Here's what didn't work in case you want to go down that road:

- opacity: 0; fill-opacity:1;
- enable-background: accumulate; on parent element
- adding a white rectangle of 100% width and height
- setting some large white stroke, setting no stroke, nor playing with stroke opacity.

What *did* work, was creating another blended element somewhere on the page. Not even interacting with the svg in any way FFS!

```
.blend-fix {
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
}
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/sashakevich/pen/qmGBBL